# Resizing Behavior Button Missing From Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode 6.3 installed on 3 Macs with the latest version of Yosemite and on every one of them the `Resizing Behavior` button is missing. I can't find any Preference or View setting to bring it back. I've scoured the internet, but I can't find anyone with a similar issue. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode with no joy.

Anyone else have this issue?

[image]

Comment: Yes I discovered it too and its pretty frustrating.

Comment: What were you using this button for?

Comment: This menu item when clicked is/was pretty useful if u had both Siblings and Ancestors and Descendants clicked. The subviews inside the control will resize based on ur constraints when u resized the view. This is one step better than trying to see what it looks like under different resolutions.

Comment: I got this response on the Apple Developer Forums from a gentleman, I assume works for Apple as his location is Cupertino: 

"This button was intentionally removed, due to the amount of confusion is caused (people often got in siblings mode without realizing it) and for performance considerations during resizing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been removed permanently. Apple says it caused confusion with siblings and descendents. Check out the Stack button on the same toolkit; Apple recommends using Stack Views before pinning